# Confused about variable declaration

Tags: c

What does this code mean?

`int c, sign;`

`sign = (c == '-') ? -1 : 1;`

I only know integers as numbers. What do the question mark etc. mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the ternary operator.

```
sign = (c == '-') ? -1 : 1;
```

and the code above is equivalent to

```
if(c == '-') sign =-1;
 else sign=1;
```

To explain more about the ternary operator :

the syntax is :

```
(condition)? do this if condition is true:do this if condition is false
```

Another example you can use it for :

```
   int a=1;
   printf( "Value of test is %d\n", (a == 1) ? 20: 30 );
```

this will print 20 if a==1 is true and 30 if a==1 is false